# Using Dates from Cell or named Range in Sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I have created a sheet to extract data from a Microsoft SQL database to produce a customer report between 2 date `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

I have been playing with a few things but have not been successful in anyway. I have searched  but have not been able to find anything that was what I was after or able to understand.

The problem I believe is data type of the date I am using in Excel and trying to pass it to the SQL query. I understand I need to convert this in some way to make this possible and correct.

If I manually enter dates into the query it works fine. But not practical for customer use
I am not experience with this and am just! stubbing my way through it. If someone would be so kind to me with this would be much appreciated.

Below is the code I am trying to use

```vb
Sub DataExtract()
'
DataExtract Macro
'

' Create a connection object.
 Dim cni96X As ADODB.Connection
 Set cni96X = New ADODB.Connection

' Set Database  Range

' Provide the connection string.
Dim strConn As String
Dim Lan As Integer
Dim OS As Integer
Dim PointID As String


' Set Variables
Lan = Range("Lan").Value
OS = Range("OS").Value
PointID = Range("PointID").Value
StartDate = Range("StartDate").Value
EndDate = Range("EndDate").Value


'Use the SQL Server OLE DB Provider.
 strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;"

'Connect to 963 database on the local server.
strConn = strConn & "DATA SOURCE=(local);INITIAL CATALOG=i96X;"

'Use an integrated login.
strConn = strConn & " INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"

 'Now open the connection.
cni96X.Open strConn

' Create a recordset object.
Dim rsi96X As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rsi96X1 As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsi96X = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rsi96X1 = New ADODB.Recordset

With rsi96X
    ' Assign the Connection object.
     .ActiveConnection = cni96X
    ' Extract the required records1.
    .Open "SELECT ModuleLabel, originalAlarmTime FROM LastAlarmDetailsByTime WHERE (os = " & OS & " And theModule = N'" & PointID & "'AND AlarmCode = N'DI=1' And lan = " & Lan & " And originalAlarmTime BETWEEN N'" & StartDate & "' AND N'" & EndDate & "') ORDER BY originalAlarmTime DESC"
    ' Copy the records into sheet.
    Range("PointLabel, TimeCallInitiated").CopyFromRecordset rsi96X


With rsi96X1
    .ActiveConnection = cni96X
    ' Assign the Connection object.
    .Open "SELECT originalAlarmTime FROM LastAlarmDetailsByTime WHERE (os = " & OS & " And theModule = N'" & PointID & "'AND AlarmCode = N'CDI1' And lan = " & Lan & " And originalAlarmTime BETWEEN N'" & StartDate & "' AND N'" & EndDate & "')ORDER BY originalAlarmTime DESC"
     ' Copy the records into sheet.
    Sheet1.Range("TimeCallEnded").CopyFromRecordset rsi96X1
    ' Tidy up
    .Close
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You must format your dates like: `StartDate = Formta(Range("StartDate").Value,[Format])` Where `[Format]` is `YYYYMMDD` or  `YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot specify the data types, the Access database engine (formerly Jet) must guess. You can influence its guesswork by changing certain registry settings (e.g. `MaxScanRows`) and including `IMEX=1` in the connection string. For more details, see [this knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819).

---

Here's something I wrote on the subject many years ago (if you google for "ONEDAYWHEN=0" you can see it has been widely read though perhaps not carefully enough!):

The relevant registry keys (for Jet 4.0) are in:

Hkey_Local_Machine/Software/Microsoft/Jet/4.0/Engines/Excel/

The `ImportMixedTypes` registry key is always read (whether it is 
honored is discussed later). You can test this by changing the key to 
`ImportMixedTypes=OneDayWhen` and trying to use the ISAM: you get the 
error, "Invalid setting in Excel key of the Engines section of the 
Windows Registry." The only valid values are:

- `ImportMixedTypes=Text`
- `ImportMixedTypes=Majority Type`

Data type is determined column by column. 'Majority Type' means a 
certain number of rows (more on this later) in each column are scanned 
and the data types are counted. Both a cell's value and format are 
used to determine data type. The majority data type (i.e. the one with 
the most rows) decides the overall data type for the entire column. 
There's a bias in favor os numeric in the event of a tie. Rows from 
any minority data types found that can't be cast as the majority data 
type will be returned with a null value.

For `ImportMixedTypes=Text`, the data type for the whole column will be:

```
Jet (MS Access UI): 'Text' data type 
DDL: VARCHAR(255) 
ADO: adWChar ('a null-terminated Unicode character string')
```

Note that this is distinct from:

```
Jet (MS Access UI): 'Memo' data type 
DDL: MEMO 
ADO: adLongVarWChar ('a long null-terminated Unicode string value')
```

`ImportMixedTypes=Text` will curtail text at 255 characters as `Memo` is 
cast as `Text`. For a column to be recognized as `Memo`, majority type 
must be detected, meaning the majority of rows detected must contain 
256 or more characters.

But how many rows are scanned for each column before is decided that 
mixed and/or what the majority type is? There is a second registry 
key, `TypeGuessRows`. This can be a value from 0-16 (decimal). A value 
from 1 to 16 inclusive is the number of rows to scan. A value of zero 
means all rows will be scanned.

There is one final twist. A setting of `IMEX=1` in the connection 
string's extended property determines whether the `ImportMixedTypes` 
value is honored. `IMEX` refers to 'IMport EXport mode'. There are three 
possible values. `IMEX=0` and `IMEX=2` result in `ImportMixedTypes` being 
ignored and the default value of 'Majority Types' is used. `IMEX=1` is 
the only way to ensure `ImportMixedTypes=Text` is honored. The resulting 
connection string might look like this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; 
Data Source=C:\ db.xls; 
Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'
```

Finally, although it is mentioned in MSDN articles that `MAXSCANROWS` 
can be used in the extended properties of the connection string to 
override the TypeGuessRows registry keys, this seems to be a fallacy. 
Using `MAXSCANROWS=0` in this way never does anything under any 
circumstances. Put another way, is has just the same effect as putting 
`ONEDAYWHEN=0` in the extended properties, being none (not even an 
error!) The same applied to `ImportMixedTypes` i.e. can't be used in 
the connection string to override the registry setting.

In summary, use `TypeGuessRows` to get Jet to detect whether a 'mixed 
types' situation exists or use it to 'trick' Jet into detecting a 
certain data type as being the majority type. In the event of a 
'mixed types' situation being detected, use `ImportMixedTypes` to tell 
Jet to either use the majority type or coerce all values as `Text` 
(max 255 characters).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the date part of your SQL statement to:

```
"[...] originalAlarmTime BETWEEN '" & Format$(StartDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' AND '" & Format$(EndDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' [...]"
```

You might also try using a [parameterized query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2317225/587880).

Comment: No worries. If you're happy with the answer please accept it!