# Excel VBA ADODB Recordset - Can I set Field Data Type (ID and Number, Name as Character, BirthDate as Date)?

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I have data in the Source Excel file (Source.xlsx) (ID, Name, DOB, City). I am reading the data from Source.xlsx using an ADODB recordset. I have to Filter Data on City and take the filtered data on a new Blank File with Header rows only (City.xlsx) using ADODB recordset (adLockOptimistic) as I dont want to open the file to write data into it. I am able to write data into it but everything is being written as Text. How can I set different data types for different fields.

Comment: see if [THIS ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26543906/2140173) helps