# OleDB read excel but return wrong number format

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, oledbconnection

I need a help at reading excel with mixed type in one column.
i have a column with value like this

```
080810235707 -> text type
614810003481 -> text type
150130301951 -> text type
612130001653 -> text type
612130000354 -> text type
612130001926 -> text type
612810001877 -> text type
81130518669 -> numeric type
81130518614 -> numeric type
612130001686 -> text type
612130001119 -> text type
```

and this is my connection string:

```
string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + _view.FileName + ";Extended Properties = 'Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes; IMEX=1; ImportMixedTypes=Text; TypeGuessRows=0' ");
```

and the result is wrong when OleDB read it:

```
080810235707
614810003481
150130301951
612130001653
612130000354
612130001926
612810001877
8.11305e+010 -> the numeric become like this
8.11305e+010 -> the numeric become like this
612130001686
612130001119
```

How to set OleDB so it read all in text type not, numeric?
Thank you

---

EDIT

This is my code to read excel, how to implement the code to convert column type:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + _view.FileName + ";Extended Properties = 'Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes; IMEX=1; ImportMixedTypes=Text; TypeGuessRows=0' ");


 OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
 conn.Open();
 dtSchemaTemp = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
 conn.Close();

strSheetTemp = dtSchemaTemp.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + strSheetTemp + "]", connectionString);

adapter.Fill(ds, "ExcelData");
DataTable dt = ds.Tables["ExcelData"];
```

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/a/26543906/2140173

Comment: @vba4all I believe it's gonna work if i using the code from the link that you given above. but the application gonna used by a lot of people and it's not possible to insert `Schema.ini` to all folder, because user will upload the file from any folder. But thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

While reading excel file, you can use NUMBERFORMAT to format the cell or you can do it by converting the range to TEXT.

Check method 1) Where you format worksheet cell to TEXT:

```
 // Pull in all the cells of the worksheet
 Range cells = xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1].Cells;

 // set each cell's format to Text
 cells.NumberFormat = "@";
```

Check method 2) Where you can read the excel and format the specific range to TEXT.

```
_workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)_workBook.ActiveSheet;

//Replace A1 with your cell range
_range = _workSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");

//set the format
_range.NumberFormat = "Text";

//save the changes back to the workbook
_workBook.Save()
```

Comment: How about to converting a column of value to string??

Comment: okay, but how i implement your code to my code? i don't know how to use it. I've made an update to my question above. I put some of my code to read excel files. Thank you @PareshJ