# Oledb not reading EXCEL cell which has mixed datatype

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, oledbconnection

I have an excel code that basically reads an excel and store it in datatable object.

However it is not reading the cells correctly which has string and integer appended.

EX : Index=RANDBETWEEN(20,80).

I am expecting the cell to be read as Index=45. But instead it is reading only 45.

Note : In order to append string to random int ,I used custom dataType in Excel.

The code below :

```
  public static DataTable ConnectToExcelDb(string provider, string envFileName, string sheetName)
    {
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;';Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= + envFileName + ";");
        DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter command = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sheetName + "$]", connection);
        command.TableMappings.Add("Table", sheetName);
        dtTable.TableName = sheetName;
        try
        {
            command.Fill(dtTable);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception("Problem in Reading data from " + sheetName.ToString());
        }
        return dtTable;
    }
```

Update :
The excel formula I have used :

Custom Type : "Index="0
The forula in cell : =RANDBETWEEN(20,80)

Cell Value : Index=36.
But When i am reading from Oledb C sharp, it is taking only 36.

Comment: Have you tried appending a tick/single quote `'` to the front of the string? Can you post the full formula?

Comment: Bmo,

Since i have the formula in my cell, i cannot use     '     . 
I just updated the excel formula.

Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26537692/2140173)

Comment: This is not a dulicate, Here i am talking about reading a cell value concatenating String and an excel formula.