# Cant Read Cells Contain '$' from Excel

Tags: c#, winforms, vba, excel

I am using this code to read from excel, but there are some cells{D2 , D4 }the prog cant read them from the excel file which contain ('$') {D2 , D4}.

```
OpenFileDialog ex = new OpenFileDialog();
ex.Filter = "XLS|*.xls|All|*.*";

if (ex.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    try
    {
        var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", ex.FileName);
        var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet7$]", connectionString);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        DataTable data = ds.Tables[0];
        DATAGRID1.DataSource = data;
    }
```

So how to get  this values as shown in the picture?

[image]

Comment: It's not a formula, is it?

Comment: see if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26543906/2140173) helps

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection string to force the driver to consider all data is text and not make assumptions about numbers, dates, etc. You do this by adding "IMEX=1;":

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;IMEX=1
```

Of course you will have more work to do once you retrieve the data to cast things back to the data type you want.

Comment: Crowcoder 
First  thnaks for you support
but when i add this to my code this errors appears to me
"could not find installabele ISAM" sooo hot to solve this ??

Comment: Try the OleDb provider: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"

Comment: Crowcoder thanks again but the "Could not find installable ISAM." error still appears ... :(

Comment: Try single quotes around the extended properties: ".....='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'"

Answer (score 0):

Should force it to treat all text equally

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1""
```

Comment: JLILI Aman 
Thanks for your support but i catch this error ... 
Could not find installable ISAM.... :(